# how to query only the commits from A to B?

Tags: git

In my development sometimes a ticket evolves quite long, going through many branching and merging, meanwhile there are parallel development, so that `git log` result is not easy to comprehend. I'm looking for an easy way to filter out only the feature related developments: suppose I have development started from commit `A`, spreading out some branches, after some merging, finally reached commit `B`, how could I call 'git log' to show only the flow from `A` to `B`? i.e.

- assume all `B` 's codes come from `A` and its descendants, there's no code of `B` comes from anywhere outside of `A` family.
- commits before `A` should not be shown
- commits after `B` should not be shown
- if `A` split out to commits `A1`, `A2`, and `A3`, while only `A1` and `A2` contributes to `B`, then both shall be shown, while `A3` I would like it to be skipped.

Now I can only use `--before` and `--after` filter of `git log` to filter, it still works, but not so neat.

Hopefully there's a better solution?

Comment: Basically, `git log A..B`. See the [doc for ranges syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation).